# Getting URL of Page in Blogger

Tags: url, blogger

I just started a blog using Blogger, and I can't figure out how to get the URL of a page I have created? For example, let's say I create a page called "About". What is the URL of the page? I tried mywebsite/about but that still doesn't link to anything. I am also using a custom template, so I am not using the Pages widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
http://<your-url.com>/p/about.html
```

Changing  with your address.

For example if your address was: hello-world.com

It'ld be: http://hello-world.com/p/about.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to take it from your browsers address bar, because it can easily be for ex.  http://hello-world.com/p/about_16.html  And I still don't know if there is any way to change it. Most of the tuts say it isnt't

Answer (score 0):

I added pages widget for a moment, only to add my new page there and then to be able to get directly to my page through blog. Then I was able to check the url. Not ideal, but worked for me. If anyone has a better idea I'd be happy to learn too.

Answer (score 0):

Go to blogger.com:

- Select your desired blog
- Go to pages
- Single click the page to which you want to get the url of (or just place cursor over its name)
- Edit|View|Share... options will be seen
- Click on View
- New window opens and in the search bare you see the link to be copied and pasted where you want it
- Further I was unable to get a shortcut for this method , you have to follow these steps for every time you do this task